# My PC !!! Wont Boot , says '\Boot\BCD status:0xc000000f '

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, windowserror

Having a terrible time.

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium, on a Toshiba Satellite CF53. I recently purchased an Adata SP 600 64GB SATA3 SSD. Previously had a 500GB HDD. Everything was working fine. The C partition took up 25.3 GB. My SSD has 59.6GB (formatted capacity).

I used GParted Live to completely clone the C partition to my SSD. There was absolutely no 'system reserved' partition, I checked for that many time through many programmes,Window's build in disk partition manager, as well as in GParted. The HDD had only 2 partitions, the C one for windows and a second one for my data.

After cloning the OS, i  started the computer through  the SSD with the BIOS to test it. Win7 boots in smoothly, as always. Then , i re-boot into GParted Live and delete the C partition from my HDD , and expand the data partition, which costs me a good 5-6 hrs to move data to the left. Fine. Then, after this, I now try to boot into windows through the SSD, no luck. Shows me this -

[Picture displaying the exact error message...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU0vZ.png)

Right then, i say, let's use the installation media to recover media, yes ? Maybe its some unexplained confusion for windows (remember though, i had used the BIOS to  to boot it from SSD up, and that had worked). The installation media detects none, absolutely none, windows installs... What ????

This also means i cant use commands to rebuild the BCD, which i suspect should fix my problem (and my depressed mental health, an outcome of trying to fix a PC the whole of today). The option i have not explored is loading drivers, but this is a simple SATA AHCI (compatible with even SATA II) SSD, and it shouldn't need any drivers, right ? Plus I have no clue what drivers to load if it does need them.

Please guys, help me. Thanks to COVID-19 no PC chops are open, and i have important WFH responsibilities. Need help quick.

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: The wrong "BIOS SATA Operation" can also cause this error when changing from HDD to SSD. For me it needed to be "ATA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was likely caused because i used GParted, and some Microsoft-Windows-Proprietary tags were screwed with. Sad that GParted cant to do this but I solved my issue by doing a fresh install and magically all my programs and games in the HDD were running fine without needing reinstalling.

Would recommend using DiskGenius, an obscure but fantastic and freeware-ish software that can work with all disk formats on Windows (maybe not APFS, but thats just junkanyways) so you can do all this business successfully and also use it for Linux partitions.